# What can cause ambiguous symbol errors on one computer and not another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to work on C++ code. The project and all its contents have been written by someone else, and copied onto a shared drive. When the creator builds it on his computer, it works fine. When I try to build the solution, I get a whole bunch of these errors

```
error C2872: '<lambda0>' : ambiguous symbol could be 
 '[File].cpp(66) : anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' or 
 '[Different file].h(549) : `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>'.
```

Here's an example of a line which is said to be in error:

```
std::pair<int, std::pair<int, Point>> b) -> bool { return (a.second.second < b.second.second ); });
```

It seems like the error always occurs with a line which ends in '});'. The full code is rather enormous to show here, and it works on other computers, so presumably it's a problem with my settings or something. Can anybody hazard a guess as to what they may be?

Comment: does your compiler support c++11?

Comment: Same patch level for VS?

Comment: Thanks, STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (and juanchopanza - that helped me figure out what a lambda was). It turns out to have been a problem with my version - I was missing the patch that fixed [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535850/lambdas-and-precompiled-headers-dont-play-well-together) bug.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've seen this or not but according to MSDN page for that compiler error:

`C2872 can occur if a header file includes a using Directive (C++), and a subsequent header file is #include'd and contains a type that is also in the namespace specified in the using directive. Specify a using directive only after all your header files are specified with #include.`

[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t57wswcs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue withe ambiguous symbol problem. For me, it turns out that I was using two namespaces which have the same function but obviously different definitions. I have to stop using one of the namespaces and this solve the issue.

As an example:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace boost::accumulator;
accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::variance> > acc;
double meanval = mean (acc);
```

This will through a compilation error: `error C2872: 'mean' : ambiguous symbol` This is because both namespaces cv and boost::accumulator have the same function "mean"

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue
Installing VS2010 SP1 fixed the ambiguous `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>` issue for me.  VS2010 without the SP1 has problems with lambdas.